Make fields required in referenced schema for a specific parent
I've following schema where both "software" and "tool" under "metadata" references the same "component" subschema. "component" has "name" property as required. However I want to set both "version" property also along with "name" as required only for "software" parent object. Whereas for "tool" only "name" property is required. How do I achieve this ?
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "properties": {
        "metadata": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/metadata",
          "title": "Metadata",
          "description": "Provides additional information about a ABC."
        }
    },
              
    "definitions": {
        "metadata": {
          "type": "object",
          "title": "BOM Metadata Object",
              "properties": {
                  "software": {
                    "title": "Software",
                    "description": "The component that the ABC describes.",
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/component"
                  },
                    
                  "tool" : {
                    
                    "items": {"$ref": "#/definitions/component"}
                  }
              }
        },
        
        "component": {
            "type": "object",
            "title": "Component Object",
            "required" : ["name"],
            "properties": {
                "name": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "title": "Component Name",
                },
                "version": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "title": "Component Version",
                }
            }
        }
    }
           

      
    
}


You can do this with allOf in your software schema
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "properties": {
    "metadata": {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/metadata",
      "title": "Metadata",
      "description": "Provides additional information about a ABC."
    }
  },
  "definitions": {
    "metadata": {
      "type": "object",
      "title": "BOM Metadata Object",
      "properties": {
        "software": {
          "title": "Software",
          "description": "The component that the ABC describes.",
          "allOf": [
            {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/component"
            },
            {
              "required": [
                "version"
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        "tool": {
          "items": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/component"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "component": {
      "type": "object",
      "title": "Component Object",
      "required": [
        "name"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string",
          "title": "Component Name"
        },
        "version": {
          "type": "string",
          "title": "Component Version"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

